# What is a linear polarized photon?

Tags: photons, wavefunction, helicity

According to Dirac a 'linear' polarized photon is a superposition of left and right rotating photons. Here is a puzzling aspect of this superposition.
There are dichroic materials which can absorb only left photons. What is their effect on this superposition? They would absorb the left state and let the right. It turns out that there are two photons in a 'linear' photon! The mechanical momentum of the dichroic material must be measurable in principle  (like Beth experiment). It would be expected that there is some energy hv absorbed too but it must be in the right photon also. Conservation of energy seems broken? 
If there is no momentum and no energy absorbed in the dichroic the conservation laws are also severely harmed. At least something happens to that photon (linear to right which is easy to show) but nothing happens to the causer of this event (namely to the dichroic). 
I see that there must be wavefunction collapse for the photon and in fact the question boils out to:
Is something physically happening to the machinery causing the collapse?

Comment: After thinking about this for several minutes I have decided I don't understand what your question is.  The Beth experiment was *hard*, because the energy and momentum carried by each photon is small. There's no evidence for non-conservation of energy or momentum or angular momentum in dichroic interactions (that would be what's commonly called a ticket-to-Stockholm observation). You are free to switch from one photon basis (left/right circular) to another (horizontal/vertical polarized) to another (diagonal polarized) as you see fit to make your problem simpler, and people do, successfully.

Comment: As soon as the electromagnetic field interacts with matter, one has to model the interaction with an effective field theory that includes new quasiparticles (or better "quasiquanta"). To ask "what happens to photons" misses the actual physics of optical interactions.

Comment: @Rob  I try to reformulate the issue as you say you don't understand. Maybe other don't understand too.   Let a linear polarized photon having E=hv passes through a dichroic plate which lets just left polarized photons pass. As the linear polarized photon is superposition of left and right photons a left polarized photon will leave the plate. The plate must receive angular momentum h as the photon has -h. But this must also imply there is some energy left in the plate. It must  be   hv.   Now this directly means that the linear photon has not E=hv but 2hv.  This of course is contradiction.

Comment: @CuriousOne   I don't think it is necessary to follow exactly what is happening inside the plate and how the propagation will happen. The speech goes about the two conservation laws (angular momentum and energy).

Comment: Both laws are valid. What's the question, then? How to use QFT properly (that's the theory that has "photons")? That's a year of your life in school... I am afraid. Just like rob I don't understand your question. You are making false assumptions (that the frequencies of the light don't change because you are not willing to model the interaction with matter properly) and then you are wondering why you are getting false results.

Comment: Do I have to state the question as for a five year old? If you know something about frequency tell it to answer what happens, politely, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

There is a misunderstanding about two properties of photons. The first property is the orientation of the electrons electric field component. From a thermal source this component - as well as the magnetic field component - is randomly distributed in space, of course in vacuum always perpendicular to the direction of propagation. A well designed polarizer align approx. 50% of the photons and behind the polarizer their electric fields are oriented in the same direction. But still behind the slits exist a second property. Photons exist with spin orientation in two opposite directions. Suppose, behind the slits the electric field component will be oriented from minus to plus in the horizontal direction from left to right:

[image]

Now there are exact two possibilities for the orientation of the magnetic field component: up - down or down - up (don't care about the shift of the amplitudes).

The sequence of the electric and magnetic field components is called the intrinsic spin of a photon. The second possible state is:

[image]

Beside this the source could give the photon a torque and the photons field components will rotate. But a photon is a photon and never the superposition of two photons.

Comment: A way to get photons of the same spin is the emission from an antenna rod during a half wavelength of the modulated radio wave.

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of spin would imply that within the dichroic material an electron will change its spin state from +1/2 to -1/2.   Imagine an electron absorbing the photon and gaining energy hv.  Then, relinquishing a photon of the same energy but imparting a left spin state upon it, with the electron's spin state changing accordingly; conserving, energy and spin angular momentum for a single photon interaction.
It's not that easy to break the laws of physics.  Interesting question though, for in order to satisfy those same laws, the net spin of a linearly polarised photon must be zero, even if that zero does consist of +1 + -1.